# Timer Event Impl / Lib

Tags: java

I have to create a Timer, firing an event on an elapsed timespan.
It easy to write a Runnable with a busy wait loop. It is also easy to include a sleep statement into busy waiting to prevent massive busy waiting.
However i need a solution that is precise but still performance friendly.
Do you have any suggestions how to implement it?
I guess it could be pretty easy using any hack causing InterruptedExceptions but i dont rly know.
Is there library offering this functionality in a generic way?
I am pretty limited to java. Although, If there are good arguments to use other language impls i would try jna.

Comment: yes sry, i guess the answer is ScheduledExecutorService anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) from JDK offers this functionality